# Прозрачность у rgba перекрывает контентную часть

Tags: html, css

Задал полупрозрачность заднего фона с помощью псевдоэлемента before и rgba, но получается так, что он перекрывает контентную часть.

```css
.top-line {
    background-size: cover;
}

.top-line::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-line .logo {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.top-line a {
    color: #fff;
}

.top-line ul, .top-line li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-line .sf-menu {
    margin-top: -29px;
}

.top-line .sf-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">


        <div class="top-line" style="background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/dLfVzJ/header_bgi.png")>
            <div class="top-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="#" class="logo">Startup</a>
                        <div class="offset-6">
                            <ul class="sf-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Родителю (для чего псевдоэлемент применяется) - `position:relative;` + внутреннему блоку тоже `position:relative;`, но с `z-index:2`, чтобы перекрыть `:before`:

```css
.top-line {
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
}

.top-content {
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}

.top-line::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-line .logo {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.top-line a {
    color: #fff;
}

.top-line ul, .top-line li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-line .sf-menu {
    margin-top: -29px;
}

.top-line .sf-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-head">


        <div class="top-line" style="background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/dLfVzJ/header_bgi.png")>
            <div class="top-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a href="#" class="logo">Startup</a>
                        <div class="offset-6">
                            <ul class="sf-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </header>
```